# JS class method not executed (Rails active_storage)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am trying to integrate Uppy file uploader with Rails ActiveStorage using direct uploads. Using this snippet provided by Rails docs:

```
import { DirectUpload } from "activestorage"

class Uploader {
  constructor(file, url) {
    this.upload = new DirectUpload(this.file, this.url, this)
  }

  upload(file) {
    this.upload.create((error, blob) => {
      if (error) {
        // Handle the error
      } else {
        // Add an appropriately-named hidden input to the form
        // with a value of blob.signed_id
      }
    })
  }

  directUploadWillStoreFileWithXHR(request) {
    request.upload.addEventListener("progress",
      event => this.directUploadDidProgress(event))
  }

  directUploadDidProgress(event) {
    // Use event.loaded and event.total to update the progress bar
  }
}
```

Calling this Uploader class:

```
const uploader_obj = new Uploader(some_file, some_url)
uploader_obj.upload()
```

Or:

```
const uploader_obj = new Uploader(some_file, some_url)
uploader_obj.upload(some_file)
```

**upload(file) method doesn't get executed.** How can I run this method?

Comment: How are you trying to execute it?

Comment: const uploader_obj = new Uploader(some_file, some_url)
uploader_obj.upload(some_file)

Comment: @VadimGalygin did you manage to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to rename the `upload(file)` class method to something else  because you have `this.upload` and `upload(file)`